# Get list of transactions of a TOKEN through a Ethereum Node

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, web3js

I am using eitherscan to get list latest of transaction of a token

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0xc748673057861a797275cd8a068abb95a902e8de&page=1&offset=10&sort=desc&apikey=

However since its not very stable and very limited, I wanna try do this through web3 and a node.

is there anyone who knows how to do a call that filter latest transaction from a specific token, and output data like above? been looking around for ages.

Comment: Do you mean you only want the latest transaction?. Like a single transaction?

Comment: like last 10 or last 25